# How to (base64) encode a protobuf as a String

Tags: java, base64, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf and want to encode its binary representation in base64 (or another textual encoding) for transmission over a text protocol.  What's the cleanest way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest option is to [convert your proto to a `byte[]`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite#toByteArray()) and then use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`BaseEncoding`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) class to encode those bytes as a base64 string:

```
String asBase64 = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(proto.toByteArray());
```

This is the most straightforward, but there are a number of other roughly equivalent mechanisms. For example if you want to write the encoded data to a file or other writable resource, you could write it to an `OutputStream` returned by [`BaseEncoding.encodingStream()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#encodingStream(java.io.Writer)):

```
proto.writeTo(BaseEncoding.base64().encodingStream(fileWriter));
```

---

As of Java 8 there's also [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html), if you're not using Guava. See [`encode(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encode-byte:A-) and [`wrap(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#wrap-java.io.OutputStream-).

---

As Jon Skeet mentioned, proto3 can [map to and from JSON](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) if you don't explicitly need to transmit the data in binary format (and you're using proto3, of course).

Comment: Note that as of proto3, JSON will be supported - and is obviously rather more readable than using base64.

Comment: Thanks, added a link.

Comment: With the standard Base64 from java SE: `String asBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToStrng(proto.toByteArray());`. Also look at `.wrap(OutputStream)`

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks; I think at the time of this answer my codebase wasn't yet on Java 8. I've updated the answer to point to `Base64` as well.